# Pug – динамическая вставка страниц

Tags: javascript, pug

Всем доброго времени суток!

**Задача:** включить несколько *.pug файлов, находящихся в массиве pages.

```
each page in pages
    include page
```

Примерно так. Но проблема в том, что судя по всему, компилятор pug не поддерживает динамические включения (dynamic inclusion).

Пробовал следующие варианты:

```
include=page
include #{page}
include `${page}`
include!=page
```

Но ничто не дало желаемого результата по вышеуказанной причине.

Как все же обойти этот недостаток и может хотя бы через js все таки реализовать некий костыль динамических включений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компилятор Pug создаёт функцию (`new Function(…)`), так что простой `include` вряд ли сработает. Но в языке есть возможность [специализировать](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html#including-filtered-text) директиву [фильтрами](https://pugjs.org/language/filters.html). Возможно, `include:pug` сработает из коробки, но на всякий случай в реестре npm уже есть [готовый](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jstransformer-pug) для Pug.

```
each page in pages
  include:pug page
```

Существенным недостатком является то, что **фильтры раскрываются при компиляции** (см. секцию [Warning](https://pugjs.org/language/filters.html)), так что переменные шаблона вроде `res.locals` им не получить<sup>*</sup>. Если нужен этот функционал, придётся писать свою функцию, которая будет вызывать скомпилированные шаблоны и передавать готовый HTML в родительский.

С другой стороны, всегда можно передать в шаблон массив функций (скомпилированных шаблонов), вызвать их с текущими locals и интерполировать результат без экранирования (`!=` или `!{}`).

<sup><sup>*</sup> Нет возможности это проверить наверняка, может и повезти, раз на выходе трансформера сам Pug. Всё зависит от конкретной реализаци компилятора, которая, правда, может и измениться.</sup>

Comment: jstransformer-pug компилирует приведенный вам код с теми же ошибками, что и обычный Pug. `no such file or directory, open '/dir/to/views/page.pug'`.

Answer (score 1):

Решено.

Код js:

```
const content = [];
fs.readdirSync("./views/main/content").forEach(function (t) {
    const ta = t.split(".");
    if (fs.statSync(path.join("./views/main/content", t)).isFile() && ["index"].indexOf(ta[0]) < 0 && ta[ta.length - 1] === "pug") {
        content.push(pug.compileFile(path.join("./views/main/content", t))())
    }
});
res.render('main/index', {content});
```

Код pug:

```
each page in content
   !=page
```

Спасибо [@elmigranto](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/210820/elmigranto), за наводку о передаче массива скомпилированных шаблонов.